# Dynamic choice for Foreign Key in Django Model

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm currently having some difficulty implementing dynamic choice for a field in my model. The model in question is as below.

```
class Item(models.Model):
    # Fields
    ...
    item_type = models.ForeignKey(Type, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Type model

```
class Type(models.Model):
    # Fields
    group = models.CharField(max_length=50, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, help_text="Enter category name")
    ...

    # Methods
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

What I want is to limit the number of `Type` returned for this field. Each of my `Type` entry has a 'group' field, and I only want to return the `Type` entry that has the same group as the group that the current user is in. For example, an user in Group "g1" when create an `Item` could only select `Type` with "g1" in group field.

I've checked out `limit_choices_to`, but I'm not sure how I can get the group of the user opening the form so that I can pass it into `limit_choices_to`. If anyone can provide an advice or any different approach to solve this it would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the `Type` model, and the `Form` you are using?

Comment: So `group` is a `CharField`? How is this related to a `User`? Where do you store the "group" of a `User`?

Comment: I've modified save_model for TypeAdmin  and add `obj.group = request.user.groups.all()[0].name` so that when any `Type` entry is saved, then the group field will automatically be populated by the group of the request user.  (All users belong to at max 1 group).

Comment: but the problem with this is that if you later *rename* a group, then the `group` of the `Product`s will not be updated. That is why you would better use a `ForeignKey` to the `Group` model. You can then set it to `obj.group = request.user.groups.first()` instead.

Comment: I see. I indeed overlooked that. Thanks for pointing it out.
Now that assume I change the CharField to ForeignKey, then how would I still limit the Type option based on the user then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override default objects manager or add custom one. In your case would be something like this.

```
class TypesManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self, user_group):
        qs = super(TypesManager,self).get_queryset().filter(group_id=user_group.id)

class Type(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, verbose_name='Group')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, help_text="Enter category name")

    # default_manager
    objects = TypesManager()

    # custom_manager
    custom_manager = TypesManager()

    # Methods
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)'
```

You can read more about Managers here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/managers/

Or if you want to limit types only for specific form you can filter initial data in form **init**